# Why is there only one strange element in array in heap memory in C but other are ok?

Tags: c, heap-memory

I made a program to separate one main array with integers into two dynamically allocated arrays with odd and even integers.

Everything is good except one element in both of the odd and even arrays, which you can see in the output picture. I hope you understand what I mean. Also any tips on improving the code are very welcomed. Thanks in advance :)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArr(int * arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 7689, 6534, 456, 67, 7652, 879, 544, 12, 4345, 867, 44, 23545, 8, 6787, 34, 26, 56, 3, 41, 6 };
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int *arrPtr = arr;

    int *oddArr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (oddArr == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    int oddArrSize = 0;
    int *evenArr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (evenArr == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    int evenArrSize = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            oddArr = realloc(oddArr, sizeof(oddArr) + sizeof(int));
            if (oddArr == NULL) {
                return 1;
            }
            oddArr[oddArrSize] = arr[i];
            oddArrSize++;
        }
        else {
            evenArr = realloc(evenArr, sizeof(evenArr) + sizeof(int));
            if (evenArr == NULL) {
                return 1;
            }
            evenArr[evenArrSize] = arr[i];
            evenArrSize++;
        }
    }

    printf("Main arr: \n");
    printArr(arrPtr, size);

    printf("Odd arr: \n");
    printArr(oddArr, oddArrSize);

    printf("Even arr: \n");
    printArr(evenArr, evenArrSize);

    free(oddArr);
    free(evenArr);
}
```

Output: 
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KseVo.png)

Comment: `sizeof(oddArr)` doesn't do what you think it does. It is same as `sizeof(int *)` and not the size of the `malloc` buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not growing the arrays correctly with `realloc()`.

```
oddArr = realloc(oddArr, sizeof(oddArr) + sizeof(int));
```

`sizeof(oddArr)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the array it points to. So every time you call `realloc()` you're allocating the same size array, not increasing the size.

That needs to be:

```
oddArr = realloc(oddArr, (oddArraySize + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

And you have to do the same thing for the even array.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @Mackovic Well, then, mark this answer as soon as you are allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

`evenArr = realloc(evenArr, sizeof(evenArr) + sizeof(int));` is incorrect, as that is always allocating the same size, since `sizeof(evenArr)` is constant. You want:

```
evenArr = realloc(evenArr, evenArrSize * sizeof *evenArr);
```

and you'll need to increment evenArrSize correctly, as well.  As in, you need to increment it before you call realloc, not after. Although it is a bit atypical to increment by one and realloc for every datapoint.  A common pattern is to double the size only when needed, or increment by a chunk size larger than 1.

Comment: Need to add 1 to `evenArrSize`, since it hasn't been incremented yet.